# ubuntu 16.04 installation "please remove installation media and press enter" Error

Tags: boot, 16.04

I tried installing Ubuntu  16.04 using USB drive on my dell vostro 15 laptop which had windows 10 on it. I somehow installed it but after I press the restart button laptop reboots and says "please remove installation media and press enter" but when I did that the laptop rebooted and displayed  "no boot device found. Press any key to reboot the machine".  I don't understand what the problem is pls help!!!

Comment: The first thing to try is the Boot-repair tool https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Actually the first thing to check is the boot order in BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: Actually the first thing to check is the boot order in BIOS/UEFI.                                                                                                                                                                    I checked my boot order actually it was wrong then i corrected the order   and installed ubuntu and it worked!!!!                                                   Thank you!!