# Ubuntu 16.04.2 install from usb drive results in blank screen

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, amd-graphics

I tried to install the latest version of Ubuntu and after selecting the option from the menu to "Install Ubuntu" it hangs on a blank screen.

I have seen other posts related to this and tried their solutions, however I have had no success. I was able to install 15.04 however the resolution is terrible and want to upgrade so that it would possibly fix this problem. I ran 
`inxi -Fxxxz` in case you needed more info about my computer:

```
    System:     Kernel: 3.19.0-82-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 4.9.2)
       Desktop: Unity 7.3.2 (Gtk 3.14.13-0ubuntu1) dm: lightdm
       Distro: Ubuntu 15.04 vivid
    Machine:   System: HP product: HP Pavilion Notebook Chassis: type: 10
       Mobo: HP model: 80AF v: 81.32
       Bios: American Megatrends v: F.41 date: 09/19/2016
    CPU:       Quad core AMD A10-8700P Radeon R6 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G (-MCP-) cache: 4096 KB
       flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm) bmips: 14373
       clock speeds: min/max: 1300/1800 MHz 1: 1600 MHz 2: 1300 MHz
       3: 1600 MHz 4: 1300 MHz
    Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Device 9874
       bus-ID: 00:01.0 chip-ID: 1002:9874
       Display Server: X.Org 1.17.1 drivers: fbdev,ati (unloaded: vesa,radeon)
       Resolution: 800x600@75.0hz
       GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 128 bits)
       GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.9 Direct Rendering: Yes
    Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device 157a
       driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:09.2 chip-ID: 1022:157a
       Card-2 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
       driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:01.1 chip-ID: 1002:9840
       Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k3.19.0-82-generic
    Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast        Ethernet controller
       driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: e000
       bus-ID: 02:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8136
       IF: eth0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
       Card-2: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       driver: bcma-pci-bridge bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 14e4:4365
       IF: N/A state: N/A mac: N/A
    Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1008.3GB (0.5% used)
       ID-1: /dev/sda model: TOSHIBA_MQ01ABD1 size: 1000.2GB serial: 1685P1RBT temp: 36C
       ID-2: USB /dev/sdb model: USB_DISK size: 8.1GB serial:    DISK-0:0 temp: 0C
    Partition: ID-1: / size: 242G used: 4.6G (2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5
    RAID:      System: supported: N/A
       No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
       Unused Devices: none
    Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 48.0C mobo: N/A
       Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
    Info:      Processes: 196 Uptime: 6 min Memory: 625.3/7364.8MB
       Init: systemd v: 219 runlevel: 5 default: 2 Gcc sys: 4.9.2
       Client: Shell (bash 4.3.301 running in gnome-terminal-)
    inxi: 2.2.16
```

Answer (score 0):

adding

> nomodeset

Before installing Ubuntu should do the trick

If you are prompted with a graphical interface of the Ubuntu installation there should be an option to tick **nomodeset** in the bottom right corner.

However if you are prompted with grub like version of the Ubuntu installation, highlight "install Ubuntu" but don't press enter just yet add **nomodeset** right after where it says splash then resume the installation.

Comment: So I am prompted with a grub like version of the Ubuntu installation. I am assuming that you mean to highlight the "install Ubuntu" then press 'e' and to enter in nomodeset there? Because I did not see a quickstart option in the grub menu. But after pressing 'e' I did not see quickstart there either and when I entered nomodeset at the bottom, it said that the nomodeset command is not recognized. These are the only parameters I see when I press e 
`set gfxpayload=keep 
 linux /casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper onbiquity quiet splash ---
initrd  /casper/initrd.lz`

Comment: My bad I meant add nomodeset right after where it says splash and you are good to go

Comment: Ok sooo that allowed me to finish the install process, i.e it said, "the installation is complete" but right after it takes me to a Ubuntu booting page and says to "remove media key and press enter" when I press enter a terminal starts to appear everytime I press enter, like it's ripping the page or something, and it just hangs on that Ubuntu boot screen. Then when I manually restart it, it just takes me to the Grub terminal. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Check the boot order in your BIOS http://askubuntu.com/q/882304/479889

Comment: So I checked boot order, it shows Ubuntu option and when I select it, it very quickly displays some errors (so quick that I can't read it) and then goes to the grub terminal. Do you know what else I should try?